# Is SVN Trying To Process My Committed Code?

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I have a problem with SVN that I just cannot figure out.  Whenever I try to commit the following block of C# code to my SVN remote repo, I am getting a CheckSum mismatch error.

**Notice that the entire block of code is commented out**.

**The file only contains the commented out code displayed below.  There is NOTHING else in the file.**

---

### The Code

---

```
/* private void CreateSvnInfoFile()
    {
        try
        {
            SvnInfoEventArgs svnInfo;
            using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
            {
                client.GetInfo(solutionDir, out svnInfo);
            }

            FileInfo svnOut = new FileInfo(this.targetDir + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "SvnInfo.xml");
            if (svnOut.Exists)
                svnOut.Delete();

            File.WriteAllLines(svnOut.FullName, new List<string>()
                {
                    "<SvnInfo>",
                    "    <Path>" + svnInfo.Uri.ToString() + "</Path>",
                    "    <Revision>" + svnInfo.Revision.ToString() + "</Revision>",
                    "</SvnInfo>"
                }.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    } */
```

---

### The Error

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

**To test this, here are the steps I followed:**

1. In my local dir, I created .cs file named "BLEEPBLOOP.cs" with nothing in the file.
2. Using TortoiseSVN, I right-clicked the file and selected "Add"
3. Using TortoiseSVN, I right-clicked the file and selected "Commit"
4. The file is now visible up in the SVN Remote Repo.
5. I opened my local copy of BLEEPBLOOP.cs and copy/pasted the above code-block into the file.
6. Saved the file.
7. Using TortoiseSVN, I right-clicked the file and selected "Commit"
8. The error message is then displayed.

---

How is this possible?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Are other files OK?  You might have hidden/illegal characters in the text.  You could try opening it with notepad and then doing a "Save As..." with a specific encoding (like ANSI).

Comment: @SteveWellens Yes, all the other files are ok.  I went ahead and tried the suggestion of doing a SAVE AS with ANSI encoding, but get the same results.

Comment: Is there any significance to the fact that TortoiseSVN is talking about BLEEP_BLOOP.cs while AnhkSVN is talking about Executor.cs?  (Or is the latter just a screenshot of the real error before you tried to reproduce it with BLEEP_BLOOP.cs?)  Also is there any significance to the difference between BLEEP_BLOOP and BLEEPBLOOP?

Comment: Oh, also, any chance this could be due to an SVN version mismatch between Tortoise and Ankh?

Comment: @adv12 Sorry.  You're correct.  The latter screenshot is of the original error.  The other screenshot is from me reproducing the problem using BLEEP_BLOOP.cs.  There's no significance to the name BLEEP_BLOOP.  I just threw in some random name so it would stick out from everything else.

Comment: Subversion doesn't modify the contents of your commit. Do you have any hook scripts on the server? How about antivirus?

Answer (score 1):

When you get a checksum error, the problem is not that the in-workingcopy version of that file is corrupted... but its pristine version. (You are allowed to change your working copy file ;-))

Somehow the data stored in your working copy as something like .svn/pristine/AA/AABBCCDDEE00112233445566....svn-base is different than the one that Subversion expected to be there.

Did you accidentally run a search and replace over that directory? (That is the most likely cause for this problem)

Comment: Bert-  That's the weird thing about this.  I can create a brand new local file with the above code.  No file with that name exists in SVN.  I commit the new file up to SVN and it says there's a checksum error.  How can there be a checksum error, if the comparison file doesn't even exist in SVN?

Comment: Wonder why I got the down-vote on this post?  Pretty sure I provided more than enough documentation of exactly what I did.  Included multiple visual examples.  It was very detailed.  Guess someone figured it wasn't quite enough.....